# share Stylus variables across Meteor packages

Tags: meteor, scope, export, package, stylus

consider the following app structure:

```
app.html
app.coffee
app.styl ## global styles, e.g. primary = #222
packages/
    FirstPackage/
        package.styl ## package styles, e.g. background: primary
    SecondPackage/
        package.styl
    ThirdPackage/
        package.styl
```

how can the packages use the styles defined `app.styl`?

Answer (score 1):

**This is possible with the meteor stylus package:**

When adding the file to share in `package.js` *(package name: `project:name`)*, mark it as 'importabe' by adding `{isImport: true}`:

`api.addFiles('file.styl', 'client', {isImport: true});`

Then import that file into stylus files of other packages:

`@import '{project:name}/file.styl'`

More info: https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/stylus#cross-packages-imports

Answer (score 0):

take a look here: http://s-grid.meteor.com/#stylusconfiguration This is hard with Meteor for now. But you can add more paths to Stylus build plugin. Here you will find how to do this with package which provide stylus build plugin with config .json file for it: http://s-grid.meteor.com/#additionalincludepaths

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you explain a little more how this works? is `app.styl` already included, and the above would add the `package.style` files to the same place, therefore I can use `@import` from within `package.style` to access the values in `app.style`?

Comment: Hmmm, I am afraid that I misunderstood the question, this solution could help you only when you want to include your package.styl file in your app.styl file. This is how we want it in most situations. I don't think that you will be able to include your app.styl file in your package.styl file :/ Packages are separated and only can export some api. Also packages are loading first.